# Nested JSON golang maps

Tags: json, go, struct, types, nested

I can't find the same problem like mine.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    result: "true",
        data: [
         { 
          randomName: {
                 val: 2,
                 secval: 0.142412,
                 thirdval: 0.5235325,
          },
          secRandomName: {
                 val: 8,
                 secval: 0.152512,
                 thirdval: 0.6574,
          },
          thiRandomName: {
                 val: 6,
                 secval: 0.4121,
                 thirdval: 0.2123
          },
        }
    ]
}`
```

How to make a type that works with the JSON sample in golang, I've tried something like this:

```
type TheData struct {
Result  string              `json:"result"`
Data    map[string]DataInfo `json:"data"`
}

type DataInfo struct {
Value           int         `json:"val"`
SecondValue     float32     `json:"secval"`
ThirdValue      float32     `json:"thirdval"`
}
```

but it is wrong.

P.S. Sorry for my English, I hope you understand. Thanks.

Comment: its should be like data.Data["randomName"].val = 2

Comment: That is not valid JSON.  Please revise your question to include valid JSON.

Comment: in this the problem, json shouldt be valid, and i need to parse it way it is

Comment: You can't use a JSON parser to parse something that isn't JSON. If you can't get a hold of valid JSON, you'll have to find a way to turn it into valid JSON, or write your own parser.

Comment: okay, thanks, just thought there in golang were some things to parse invalid json

Answer (score 1):

Is that really representative of your data?  It's not valid JSON.  See description at [json.org](http://json.org/).  In particular you need quotes around the strings, and commas should not be present after the last member of an object or array.  It's odd that `"true"` is a string instead of a boolean.  Since this clearly isn't a copy/paste of your data, are you sure you got the square brackets and curly braces right?  Those are important to the answer.

Assuming you did get those right... From these lines:

```
data: [
         { 
          randomName: {
```

We can tell that `data` is an array of objects.  If you meant the square braces, it's an error that the array is not represented in your data model.  Alter your data model to include a slice to capture the JSON array:

```
type TheData struct {
    Result string                `json:"result"`
    Data   []map[string]DataInfo `json:"data"`
}
```